# Displaying a popover inside Modal for bootstrap twitter library

Tags: ajax, twitter-bootstrap, modal-dialog, popover

I call a page using jquery ajax, and get the response and display it in bootstrap modal.
This page displays a popover when it's called in the browser separately using the function

```
   $('a[rel=popover]').popover();
```

the popover appears, but inside the modal the popover doesn't appear.

### Update:

the problem is JS problem, where the error is  `$('a[rel=popover]').popover` is not a function

Answer (score 2):

See the problem here is that the popover is displayed even inside the modal but as the z-index of modal is greater than that of the popover you would not be able to see it. I changed the z-index of the popover element and now it is working, so you can refer this **[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/phpdeveloperrahul/nzUhj/)** to see a live example.

CSS :

```
.popover{
    z-index:100000000;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

With Bootstrap you'll find that the popover and the modal have the same z-index:

```
.modal .popover,.modal .twipsy{z-index:12000;}
```

You'll need to manually over ride the popover z-index if the containing element is a modal: I'm not sure you can use CSS to do it, but you can definitely do it in js.

Comment: Thanks for you response, but I forgot to mention the problem is JS problem, where the error is  $('a[rel=popover]').popover is not a function

Comment: You're either not loading the bootstrap popover library somehow, or the modal is being added to the page in a way that prevents the popover library from adding the appropriate function to the page.